# Firebase V9 Online Status

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to reconfigure some Firebase v8 code to firebase v9 in React...  On a login/register page, I want to change the online status to true.

I'm not sure if this line of code will be much different or quite literally the same with updated variable names. This may be a very simple question (hopefully). I know in v9 a lot of these types of things are restructured with an import statement of a function already available in the firebase library. IDK if this is one of those things... :/. Thanks for your time! Let me know in advance if I need to include more of the code to make sense...

**old (working) v8 code:**
**variables:**

- **projectAuth** = firebase.auth()
- **projectFirestore** = firebase.firestore()

focusing on the line just below: "// set online to be true"
...within the login / register page:

```
try {
  // login
  const res = await projectAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

  //set online to be true
  await projectFirestore.collection('users').doc(res.user.uid)
    .update({ online: true })

    // dispatch login action
  dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', payload: res.user })

  if (!isCancelled) {
    setIsPending(false)
    setError(null)
  }
}
```

**My v9 Code:**
**variables:**

- **auth** = getAuth()
- **db** = getFirestore()

```
    try {
      // login
      await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((res) => {

        // dispatch login action
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', payload: res.user })

        //set online to be true
        await projectFirestore.collection('users').doc(res.user.uid)
          .update({ online: true })
        
        if (!isCancelled) {
          setIsPending(false)
          setError(null)
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a top level function `updateDoc()` to update documents:

```
import { updateDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, "users", res.user.uid)

await updateDoc(docRef, { online: true });
```